# Delete cascade hangs in JPA when large number of objects

Tags: java, jpa

I have a JPA Entities like this:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity{
    @JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "application", cascade = ALL, fetch = LAZY)
private List<MyChildEnity> myChildEntities;
}
...
@Entity
class MyChildEnity {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { REFRESH,
        DETACH })
@JoinColumn(name = "APPLICATION_ID")
private MyEntity application;
}
```

I access this entity from a REST call. When the number of elements is very large, and I try to delete the MyEntity Object the REST call hangs and then timeout. For small number of elements in MyChildEnity table it works fine. When I debugged, I saw that JPA fetches one record at a time and deletes it. This is too slow and too much work done.

Is this an expected behavior? Shouldn't JPA be intelligent to convert this to a single DELETE call on the MyChildEnity table.

I'm using OpenJPA with Derby and DB2 database.

Comment: Suggest you post the SQL being invoked, and work out what each is for. e.g 1 SQL to pull back the elements of the List, then 1 SQL to pull back other fields of the child??? if so which fields?

Comment: Yes... First there is a SELECT to get all the elements and then one DELETE call for every entry in that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get one delete statement for each element probably has something to do with the fact that JPA let you do something pre- and post removal. If you write a JPQL with a `delete`statement you are able to bypass the callback mechanism and delete everything in a single request.

[Documentation for entity listeners and callbacks.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html) (This is JPA functionality).